# Mapping data from multiple arrays of objects to a new object in Javascript using functional programming

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I am trying to create an object that requires mapping
data from four arrays included in a function. The goal
is to accomplish the new map using functional programming.
Thus, for example, the methods map, reduce, forEach, concat, and
filter would be allowed as well as custom functions.

I have arrived at a non functional solution using for-loops,
which I've included below. However, I get stuck on a purely 
functional approach.

The data set and data for the desired outcome can be
viewed independently at http://jhusain.github.io/learnrx/, though I've included the data below.

The objective is to re-map the data using functional programming so that it resembles the desired output (included below).

I would appreciate help re-mapping the data using a functional approach
and starting from the data shown below.

The exact text of the problem states:

> Exercise 26: Converting from Arrays to Deeper Trees
>
> Let's try creating a deeper tree structure. This time we have 4
>   seperate arrays each containing lists, videos, boxarts, and bookmarks
>   respectively. Each object has a parent id, indicating its parent. We
>   want to build an array of list objects, each with a name and a videos
>   array. The videos array will contain the video's id, title, bookmark
>   time, and smallest boxart url. In other words we want to build the
>   following structure:

The desired output is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "New Releases",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber",
                "time": 32432,
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture",
                "time": 3534543,
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Thrillers",
        "videos": [
            {
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard",
                "time": 645243,
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys",
                "time": 984934,
                "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The function that serves as the starting point follows below.

I've named the function "combine" so that we can call it. Also, I've
included my solution, made up of for-loops, at the end of the
function after the bookmarks array. My attempt at a functional solution only
got this far:

```
return lists.map(function(list) {
        return {
            name: list.name,
            videos:
                videos.
                    filter(function(video) {
                        return video.listId === list.id;
                    }).    // I got stuck at this point.
```

This is the starting set of data:

```
function combine() {
    var lists = [
            {
                "id": 5434364,
                "name": "New Releases"
            },
            {
                "id": 65456475,
                name: "Thrillers"
            }
        ],
        videos = [
            {
                "listId": 5434364,
                "id": 65432445,
                "title": "The Chamber"
            },
            {
                "listId": 5434364,
                "id": 675465,
                "title": "Fracture"
            },
            {
                "listId": 65456475,
                "id": 70111470,
                "title": "Die Hard"
            },
            {
                "listId": 65456475,
                "id": 654356453,
                "title": "Bad Boys"
            }
        ],
        boxarts = [
            { videoId: 65432445, width: 130, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg" },
            { videoId: 65432445, width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg" },
            { videoId: 675465, width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
            { videoId: 675465, width: 120, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg" },
            { videoId: 675465, width: 300, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" },
            { videoId: 70111470, width: 150, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg" },
            { videoId: 70111470, width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg" },
            { videoId: 654356453, width: 200, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg" },
            { videoId: 654356453, width: 140, height:200, url:"http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg" }
        ],
        bookmarks = [
            { videoId: 65432445, time: 32432 },
            { videoId: 675465, time: 3534543 },
            { videoId: 70111470, time: 645243 },
            { videoId: 654356453, time: 984934 }
        ];

        //My non-functional solution

    sizeArr = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
            lists[i].videos = [];

            for(var j = 0; j < videos.length; j++){
                if(videos[j].listId === lists[i].id){
                    lists[i].videos.push(videos[j]);

                }
            for(var k = 0; k < bookmarks.length; k++){
                if(bookmarks[k].videoId === videos[j].id && videos[j].listId === lists[i].id){
                    videos[j].time = bookmarks[k].time;
                }

            for(var l = 0; l < boxarts.length; l++){
                var size = boxarts[l].width * boxarts[l].height;
                sizeArr.push(size);
                sizeArr = sizeArr.sort(function(min, max){
                    if(min < max){
                        return min;
                    }

                     if(boxarts[l].videoId === videos[j].id && videos[j].listId === lists[i].id){
                        videos[j].boxart = boxarts[l].url;
                    } 

                });
            }

            }

            }
            delete lists[i].id;
        }

    return lists;
}
combine();
```

Comment: Seems like all you have left to do is `.forEach()` over the videos you filtered, and for each video, `.forEach()` *(or `.reduce()`)* over the `boxart` array and find the entry with the `videoId` matching the current `video.id` and assign its `url` property to `video.boxart`. Then do similarly  with `bookmarks`.

Comment: Thank you. I may have been too focused on using filter() to the exclusion o the other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, but it's not that efficient. You first could create dictionaries or maps from your arrays to allow quick id lookups. That would eliminate the need for filters.

I also avoided to mutate the initial data structures.

```js
 var lists = [{
     "id": 5434364,
     "name": "New Releases"
   }, {
     "id": 65456475,
     name: "Thrillers"
   }],
   videos = [{
     "listId": 5434364,
     "id": 65432445,
     "title": "The Chamber"
   }, {
     "listId": 5434364,
     "id": 675465,
     "title": "Fracture"
   }, {
     "listId": 65456475,
     "id": 70111470,
     "title": "Die Hard"
   }, {
     "listId": 65456475,
     "id": 654356453,
     "title": "Bad Boys"
   }],
   boxarts = [{
     videoId: 65432445,
     width: 130,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber130.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 65432445,
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber200.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 675465,
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 675465,
     width: 120,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture120.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 675465,
     width: 300,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 70111470,
     width: 150,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard150.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 70111470,
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard200.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 654356453,
     width: 200,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys200.jpg"
   }, {
     videoId: 654356453,
     width: 140,
     height: 200,
     url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys140.jpg"
   }],
   bookmarks = [{
     videoId: 65432445,
     time: 32432
   }, {
     videoId: 675465,
     time: 3534543
   }, {
     videoId: 70111470,
     time: 645243
   }, {
     videoId: 654356453,
     time: 984934
   }];


 var videosByList = lists.map(function(list) {
   return {
     name: list.name,
     videos: videos.filter(function(video) {
       return video.listId == list.id;
     }).map(function(video) {
       return {
         id: video.id,
         title: video.title,
         time: bookmarks.filter(function(bookmark) {
           return bookmark.videoId == video.id;
         }).pop().time,
         boxart: boxarts.filter(function(boxart) {
           return boxart.videoId == video.id;
         }).sort(function(a, b) {
           return a.url < b.url ? 1 : (a.url > b.url ? -1 : 0);
         }).pop().url
       };
     })
   };
 });


 document.querySelector('pre').appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(videosByList, null, 4)))
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Good idea to not mutate the originals. Presort the `boxarts` (or a copy of it) according to `width * height` and then use the ES6 `.find()` instead of `.filter()` for `boxart` and `time`, and that'll go a long way for performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
function combine () {

  var Genres = [];

  lists.forEach(function(genre) {
    var currGenre = makeGenre(genre.name, []);

    videos.filter(function(video){
      if (video.listId === genre.id) {
        return video;
      }
    }).forEach(function(video) {

      var time = bookmarks.filter(function(mark){
        if (video.id === mark.videoId) {
          return mark.time;
        }
      })[0];

      var art = boxarts.filter(function(art){
        if (video.id === art.videoId) {
          return art;
        }
      }).sort(function (a, b) { return a.width * a.height > b.width * b.height; })[0];

      currGenre.videos.push(makeVideo(video.id, video.title, time, art));
    });
    Genres.push(currGenre);
  });
  return Genres;
}

function makeGenre (name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    videos: []
  };
}

function makeVideo (id, title, time, boxart) {
  return {
    id: id,
    title: title,
    time: time,
    boxart: boxart
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. A really helpful lesson in functional programing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Show Answer" button in the exercise page linked by the OP. I guess the answer button was not working in the OP's chosen browser, so I have pasted the solution here, including extra background information for the exercise:

```
return lists.map(function(list) {
  return {
    name: list.name,
    videos: 
      videos.
        filter(function(video) {
          return video.listId === list.id;
        }).
        concatMap(function(video) {
          return Array.zip(
            bookmarks.filter(function(bookmark) {
              return bookmark.videoId === video.id;
            }),
            boxarts.filter(function(boxart) {
              return boxart.videoId === video.id;
            }).
        reduce(function(acc,curr) {
              return acc.width * acc.height < curr.width * curr.height ? acc : curr;
            }),
            function(bookmark, boxart) {
              return { id: video.id, title: video.title, time: bookmark.time, boxart: boxart.url };
            });
      })
  };
});
```

The exercises build on previous knowledge, which demonstrate the `concatMap` function (see Exercise 13 for the implementation), pasted here for convenience:

```
Array.prototype.concatMap = function(projectionFunctionThatReturnsArray) {
  return this.
    map(function(item) {
      return projectionFunctionThatReturnsArray(item);
    }).
    // apply the concatAll function to flatten the two-dimensional array
    concatAll();
};
```

`concatAll` is defined in Exercise 10, pasted here for convenience:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
  var results = [];
  this.forEach(function(subArray) {
    results.push.apply(results, subArray);
  });

  return results;
};
```

The exercise instructions also dictate: "There's just more one thing: you can't use indexers. In other words, this is illegal `var itemInArray = movieLists[0];`"

**Edit**

New information from OP. It seems like the OP would like to run the exercise without the context of the exercise page and see the answer produced to verify that it is correct. To do this you need some extra functions to be defined because the exercises implement slightly different versions to those supplied by default in JavaScript (i.e `filter`, `map`, `reduce`, `concatMap`, `concatAll`, `zip`). If you use the default JavaScript versions then results go missing as the OP described.

For your convenience, I have setup the required functions and the solution and logged the answer to the console in jsbin.com: 
http://jsbin.com/tolupe/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you for contributing! The show button was working, but I mounted the solution you have posted in Chrome dev tools along with the concatAll, concatMap, and zip functions. The function returned empty arrays. From that I assumed there was a bug in the answer.

Comment: @davisec52 You are welcome. I have edited my answer to include a standalone answer to the exercise in order to show that there is no bug. I was able to replicate getting empty arrays when the extra functions are not available to the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and taking the time to mount the solution on jsbin. I see now that the the solution does work, and that I was incorrect in assuming a flawed solution. Your response provides clarity and understanding to the entire functional programming tutorial. Much appreciated!

Comment: @davisec52 My pleasure. I learned a lot from going through the exercise as well.